# SuperDrive not accepting discs after failed FCPX burn

Tags: mac-mini, optical-drive, dvd

I had a working Apple SuperDrive until about half an hour ago.

I was burning a school project to disc from Final Cut Pro X when it suddenly failed and returned an error. The disc showed up as Untitled Disc and Untitled Disc 2 on my desk. Not knowing what was going on, I deleted them both as the disc had automatically been ejected and then threw the disc away. Now it will not accept any discs on any computer I've tried (2 Mac Minis, Late 2014)

Does anyone know the answer to this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware failure to me.

Comment: I might see if I can try it on my dads MPB or my brothers MBA.